# python - Reading file with comments syntax

Tags: python, file

Is there an existing way to read any files with python already ignoring characters that are to the right of a comment character (for example, `#`)?

For example, consider the file

```
 # this is a comment
 0, 6, 7 # this is a comment
 5, 6, 7 # this is a comment
 7, 6 # this is a comment
```

I'm looking for something that could already be called as

```
file.readcomlines()
#or
readcomlines(file)
```

and return

```
['0, 6, 7 ', '5, 6, 7 ', '7, 6 ']
```

Is there such a thing in python or I'm going to have to program this function manually? Web search was of no help at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Built-in function [`str.partition(sep)`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition)

```
line = "0, 6, 7 # this is a comment"
left_part = line.partition("#")[0]
```

Comment: So your answer is no, there isn't this by default. I have to program it myself using this. Am I right?

Comment: Won't this solution split on hashes that are part of strings, not comments?

Comment: @alexwlchan: Yes, it would. But it seems that in this scenario there are only integer-list-type parts on the left-hand side of the hash.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function that does this

```
def readcomlines(path):
    with open(path) as f:
        return [line.split('#', 1)[0] for line in f if '#' in line]
```

For example

```
>>> readcomlines('test.txt')
['', '0, 6, 7 ', '5, 6, 7 ', '7, 6 ']
```

This is, however, only a crude way to solve this and isn't particularly robust. The character `#` may show up in a number of other places other than just comments.